# Disambiguate the [mechanize] tag family

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request, tag-wiki

There are at least three libraries going by the name `mechanize`:

- [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/)
- [Python](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) and
- [Ruby](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/)

I gather that the Perl library came first, and the other two are ports.  However, they all have different maintainers and probably aren't perfect replicates in terms of functionality.  Right now [mechanize](/questions/tagged/mechanize) is a somewhat random mix of all three, but has wiki info from the Ruby library.  There's also [www-mechanize](/questions/tagged/www-mechanize), that should have just Perl questions (`WWW::Mechanize`), but has collected some Ruby and Python questions as well.

I propose sorting things out with [mechanize-python](/questions/tagged/mechanize-python), [mechanize-ruby](/questions/tagged/mechanize-ruby), and [mechanize-perl](/questions/tagged/mechanize-perl) as a synonym for [www-mechanize](/questions/tagged/www-mechanize).

I'm not sure what would be the best thing to do with the base [mechanize](/questions/tagged/mechanize).

Objections?  Desire to help?

Comment: Why do you want them separated?

Comment: I assume, perhaps incorrectly, that the problems and solutions of one aren't necessarily going to be applicable to the others, and that people who might be interested in one won't necessarily be interested in the others.  There might be issues common to all three, which is part of why I'm uncertain what would be best to do with the base 'mechanize' tag.